# Network adapter not working after a couple of minutes Windows Server 2012

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012-r2

we have been trying to solve a strange problem for the last 2 days but after a lot of searching we are stuck at the same point. We previously had Windows Server 2012 and it was working great, no problems, but decided to upgrade to R2 and that's where all our problems started.

Server:
HP PorLiant ML310e Gen8
2 Network cards ( Broadcom NetExtreme Gigabit Ethernet )
Windows Server 2012 R2

Clients:
Windows 8.1 Pro

We use one of the network cards for the server and the other for a virtual machine in Hyper-V. When the server was updated, all users, groups and permissions where created and assigned, so every member of the network could join their computers with their new users and passwords (no problem here), but when clients try to access the shared folders of the network they are unable to do so. And they can't ping the server.

So, the deal is that when the server is just started (or restarted) every client can see the network directories, can ping the server, everything works just fine for 2 or 3 minutes, then the network falls apart and there is no way for us to bring it back up other than restarting the server, but again it only works for like 3 minutes.

If we try to ping the server's IP address we get the 'General Failure' Message.

We have tried:

- Enabling and disabling network adapters
- Changing the order of the network adapters
- Hyper-V is not being started
- Disabling Network Load Balancing (NLB)
- Disabling Large Send Offload (LSO) both with netsh and in the card's properties
- Change the network adapter static IP
- Disabling IPv6
- Disabling the 'Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power'

Also noted that the server is getting several IP addresses from the DHCP. We have Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013, and SQL Server 2012 installed.

Can any of you guys please help us with this situation? we'll be very grateful :)

Thanks in advance!
Greetings!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,so this was an ol' windows trick... no matter what configuration we tried, windows server kept taking down the network minutes after it was started, so  we:

- Completely uninstall both network adapters
- Restarted the server
- Did the standar network adapter configuration (static IP addres, network, gateway, set the virtual switching for Hyper-V)

And everything started working again. So we kept the same configuration as before; Windows just needed to install the network adapters again.

Greetings!